# Stripe subscription not running in Lambda - async issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, aws-lambda, stripe-payments

I am working on a Lambda function that will create a Stripe cusotmer then follow up and create a subscription for that customer. Lambda functions are async so I have added an `await` to the create customer part but when I add it to the subscription part (see the `// tried await here`), it said that it can't use `await` on a non async function. I have ran it with just the one `await` and it only created a customer not the subscription. How can I have the Lambda function run the subscription Stripe call as well?

```
module.exports.stripe = async (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  let input = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body);
  let message = JSON.parse(input.Message)
  let companyID = message.companyID
  let plan = message.plan
  let email = message.email
  let output = {}
  console.log(message)
  await stripe.customers
        .create({
            email,
            description: companyID
        })
        .then((customer) => {
      console.log(customer)
            if (customer.id) {
        stripe.subscriptions // tried await here
          .create({
            customer: customer.id,
            trial_period_days: 14,
            items: [{plan}],
            // coupon
          })
          .then((subscription) => {
            console.log(subscription)
            if(subscription.id != null) {
              console.log('Successfully created subscription: ', subscription.id)
            } else {
              console.log('Error creating subscription for: ', customer.id)
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
              }); 
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            if (err && err.type) {
                switch (err.type) {
                    case 'StripeCardError':
                        // A declined card error
                        err.message; // => e.g. "Your card's expiration year is invalid."
                        break;
                    case 'RateLimitError':
                        // Too many requests made to the API too quickly
                        break;
                    case 'StripeInvalidRequestError':
                        // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
                        break;
                    case 'StripeAPIError':
                        // An error occurred internally with Stripe's API
                        break;
                    case 'StripeConnectionError':
                        // Some kind of error occurred during the HTTPS communication
                        break;
                    case 'StripeAuthenticationError':
                        // You probably used an incorrect API key
                        break;
                    default:
                        // Handle any other types of unexpected errors
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

  return callback(null, output)
};
```

Comment: Since you're in a `.then`, just `return` your ptomise and `.then` will await it for you... Also, in an `async` function, using a callback is unique... and pointless (promises were invented to replace callbacks).

Comment: You assigned `await` to `.then`, it does not return a promise. remove the whole then thing, and assign a variable.

Comment: @FZs Thanks will try that and the callback is not exactly my idea lol it was something I found years ago when I started with Lambdas and has worked in some default cases - ie when I am building out the function

Comment: @NirGofman Why remove and assign to a variable? I shouldn't have to create variables that don't do anything

Comment: @FZs Thanks that worked, got it to create the subscription :)

Comment: Minor recommendation: have a look at Step Functions. They are probably better suited for what you are doing here.

Comment: @Jens Thanks but I am aware of them and they provide no value here other than increased cost of running Lambda and paying for state changes. This is literally all this function will do so I am not concerned about splitting it up into different functions.